# Can Windows recovery save me?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I've been having a whole lot of issues with my triple booting laptop. If you want, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/720390/how-to-fix-my-grub-after-windows-10/720815#72081 Anyways, I've made the decision to wipe and do a reinstall using Windows recovery. I'm assuming that Windows will overwrite everything and I'll have to change the partitions around. Am I correct in this assumption? Will Windows even be able to fix itself?

If not, does anyone know of a way to obtain a product key when you can't get into Windows?

Comment: how, is your pc currently partitioned ? What are your current issues?

Comment: If you wiped there isn't anything to recover.  Just skip the step when it asks for a product key.  You need an installation media not a recovery disk, a recovery disk, cannot install Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't wiped yet. Everything is still there and I can tell Windows to reinstall. The only issue is that it won't boot. My partitions are so screwed up and I think it'll save a lot of time and frustration by doing a reinstall.

Comment: You need a Windows installation disk a WinRE cannot install Windows

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not so certain. Windows is specifically offering to reinstall.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just an update: Windows has been wiped and I'm now Kubuntu only. Dual boots are too complicated.

Answer (score -1):

In almost all of the dual boot systems I have reinstalled a host, standalone Windows OS on over GRUB it has written over with the Windows bootloader. So the answer to your question, I believe, is yes, it will solve your problem. You just need to make sure that your Windows bootloader gets installed over GRUB (which I think will happen whenever you tell the Windows Installation GUI to delete all existing partitions.)

Comment: Does installation work the same way as recovery?

Comment: I don't believe using the Recovery feature is going to affect any other partitions other than the partition the OS is installed on. However, using installation media would give you the desired outcome.

Comment: The only thing keeping me from doing that is the product key. I can't get into Windows to recover it and I'm not sure if I have it written down anywhere. Even then, it's a Windows 8 key and I want to use 10. I think I heard something about Windows updating the keys to make them match, but I'm not positive.

Comment: This may help you fix that issue: https://itsolutionsblog.net/3-ways-to-extract-the-windows-8-product-key/

Comment: Unfortunately, my computer did not come with 8 originally so the key wouldn't be living in the BIOS (I wouldn't think). I'm fairly certain that I have my key but there's a section on the Microsoft website that says this "If you bought a digital copy of Windows 10 from a Microsoft website, the product key will be in the confirmation email you received after buying it or will be distributed digitally as an entitlement, in which case you won't receive a product key. For example, if you upgraded to Windows 10 for free, you'll receive an entitlement instead of a product key."

Comment: I know it's a pain, but you'll probably need to install whatever OS you bought with the original key and then free upgrade to Windows 10 again.

Comment: So use the Windows 8.1 key or Windows 7 key you do have, but if Windows 10 is currently activated, you don't need to input any key and it will automatically activate.  Installing Windows 7 or Windows 8.x isn't required and just a waste of time.   You have a Windows key I presume so input that when asked, which will only work, if your using a Version 1511 .ISO which isn't a a recovery disk...

Comment: @brentaarnold That was something I wanted to try and avoid. Upgrading is what caused my problems in the first place.

Comment: As @Ramhound has accurately stated, you can use a Windows 7/8/8.1 key to register your WIndows 10 (Version 1511 or LATER.) The installation media you're looking for to do a fresh installation without the need of upgrade can be found here with instructions: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-media-creation-tool-create-installation-media-upgrade. If the installation media downloads an outdated version, simply update the PC to the most recent version and then register it with your key.